# Arrow hange in jquery make wrong date selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#fromDatePicker").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: "2018:+20",
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
$('.clsTable').on('focus', '#fromDatePicker', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });
});
```

I am having the date picker as shown above.but  when I change the year the month is also getting changed. I am using jquery-ui.min.js of version 1.9.1 and jquery.min.js of version 1.8.2 and jquery-ui.js of version 1.12.1. I have tried with `live` function and later found its replaced by on in new version of jquery. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add [mcve], that code is incomplete. Is there a reason for you to use such an ancient version of the libraries? Also what is the purpose of the focus-event and setting the dateformat again?